# How come the update manager won't let me upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

I have it set to notify me of all releases of ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

there two ways to do that

First way you can do it by terminal 
just copy this command and drop it in your terminal

```
update-manager -d
```

Second way 
is by doing it by yourself 
"and i prefer this method at least you know what you are doing so you can avoid some mistakes "

1- Open **Update Manager** from either the **Power Menu** or **the Dash.**

2- Click the ‘**Settings**’ button in the *lower-left corner* of the Update Manager window:

3- This will open Software Sources.

4- Click the menu next to “*Notify me of a new Ubuntu version*” and select ‘*For Any New 
   Version*’.

5- Once you’ve made the change you will likely be prompted to input your user password.
    After this, close Software Sources, then close and then reopen Update Manager.

6- You’ll now see the following prompt displayed at the top of the window of **update Manager**

```
Important Note : 
* It also pays to back-up any important files and folders before upgrade.
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
update-manager -d
```

Comment: That allows install of beta

Comment: You will need to wait for your (regional) download server to receive **final release** Ubuntu 12.10 ..  eg. a few more hours.  *Otherwise, download yourself, as Torrent.*