# My update manager won't upgrade to 12.10 from 12.04

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

I followed the steps as shown on the Ubuntu website, but when i clicked on "Check" the upgrade did not appear? Is there something I am doing wrong, or is it just not working?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-12-10 (although I'd recommend staying on 12.04).