# I can't upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

I'm on 12.04 and I go to Update Manager but it keeps saying it's up-to-date even though it doesn't have 12.10.

Is there something I have to do, some dev channel I need to be subscribed to, to get this to work?

Comment: See, [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203184/upgrade-to-12-10-from-12-04-not-available-in-update-manager), [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202707/my-update-manager-wont-upgrade-to-12-10-from-12-04) and mainly [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why) question.

Answer (score -1):

Check this guy out, [[How To] Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-12-10).