# Upgrade to 12.10 button not on Update Manager

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

I'm following the instructions on how to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10. It says to launch the Update Manager, cick the Check button to check for new updates. And press the Upgrade button after I've downloaded any 12.04 updates. But this Upgrade button never appears.

Is there a hardware limitation to 12.10 that I'm now aware of? I've got a Lenovo T400 Thinkpad with 2 GiB RAM and and Intel Core2 Duo CPU @ 2.53GHz.

Comment: Check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why).