# Upgrade to 12.10 option not showing up un Update Manager

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

The option to upgrade to 12.10 isn't popping up in Update Mananger. Something special I have to do?