# Update Manager cannot find update from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: updates, 12.10, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

I have Ubuntu 12.04. 
The update manager cant find the update to 12.10.