# Cannot Upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu to 12.10.
But the Update Manager is not giving me any kind of button like "Upgrade".

Is this due to problems with my update manager?

Should I reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Please see the answers on the possible duplicate question linked on the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Open Update manager

click setting on lower left corner of the window..

go to updates tab

on the right bottom corner select from drop down -> "For any new version"

then close and then reopen Update Manager.

It should show you the option to upgrade.

---

If after performing these step it still does not work then type :

```
update manager -d
```

Link for more details : [OMGUbuntu : how to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-12-10)

Answer (score 0):

Like so many other things in Linux, the GUI only confuses the process.  Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Follow the prompts in the terminal, and you will be running the next release in no time.