# Upgrade 12.04 to 12.10 not showing up with update manager

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10

We have a local ubuntu repo at our insti. Let us suppose that I have an 12.04 machine with the repo settings as follows:

```
deb http://<server-name>/ubuntu precise main restricted unverse multiverse
deb http://<server-name>/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted unverse multiverse
deb http://<server-name>/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted unverse multiverse
deb http://<server-name>/ubuntu precise-security main restricted unverse multiverse
deb http://<server-name>/ubuntu precise-proposed main restricted unverse multiverse
deb-src http://<server-name>/ubuntu precise main restricted unverse multiverse
deb-src http://<server-name>/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted unverse multiverse
deb-src http://<server-name>/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted unverse multiverse
deb-src http://<server-name>/ubuntu precise-security main restricted unverse multiverse
deb-src http://<server-name>/ubuntu precise-proposed main restricted unverse multiverse
```

Suppose, I were to change precise to quantal in this list, will my machine upgrade. Please tell me this as my 12.04 machine is not upgrading to 12.10. I have tried all hooks and crooks as given in the various ubuntu related forums.
 The normal upgrade method as mentioned on the ubuntu website fails in my case.

Comment: Please see possible duplicate question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why

Comment: Thanks peachy. But the crux of the question was whether a distro upgrade was possible if I change precise to quantal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look in the settings section, it has a drop down box that asked when you want to be notified about distro upgrades, set it to "for any new version" it might be set default to "for long-term support versions".

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have done all that. Did not work!

Comment: try clicking on "check" after that?

Comment: Other than that I'm sure, I don't think that changing the names on that list will give you upgrades, i think it'll just look for software upgrades on a different repository which isn't what you want. It will think that you are already upgraded. But like i said, i may not be right on that one. Sorry i couldn't help you.