# Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS to 12.10 Desktop does NOT work

Tags: dist-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

**Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS to 12.10** does NOT work.

Do NOT get **Upgrade** option.

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/a/202743/27968

Answer (score 0):

This is because the LTS version is not set up to automatically detect upgrades. To do this, open Software Updater, then go to your settings, in the Updates tab select 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version' and change to 'For any new version' rather than 'For long-term support versions'. Execute 'sudo apt-get update' in terminal, then open Software Updater once again and click on check. An option should appear for the upgrade. As a warning, these are the steps I took to upgrade my version, but had a black screen boot after doing so. It is perhaps safer to upgrade with a Live CD/USB stick and choose the upgrade option from that installer.