# Not given the option to install 12.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, 12.10, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

I followed the guide on the website to upgrade distributions. I was not effective at doing this, however, update manager doesn't give me the option to download the new release. I'm not very effective at creating and implementing terminal commands.

If someone could show me which commands to copy and paste into terminal in the form of a step-by-step guide, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In *Software Sources* (via *System Settings...*) under the tab *Updates* check that upgrades are **not** restricted to Long Term Support Ubuntu Versions

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given the 11.10 tag, I'm assuming you're using 11.10. You cannot upgrade directly from 11.10 to 12.10, but must first upgrade to 12.04 LTS.