# Priblem with Update Manager

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

I have a problem with my pc. is that my "update manager" does not at my disposal the new verision of UBUNTU 12.10 to I update my pc. I have UBUNTU 12.04 LTS verision 64-bit

I can't update to 12.10 since Update Manager doesn't offer it to me.

Comment: Please use English only.

Comment: ok ! can you answer my question please?

Comment: Please see the link given by Stephen Myall. It'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your update manager is set to update just to LTS versions.

**How to fix**

Open Update Manager, press `Settings` and select `Updates`, there set the "Alert on next Ubuntu releases" to `All releases`. (I don't use English version, so, it may differ a little the therms there.)

**Another method:**
Open a `terminal`, and type: `do-release-upgrade -d`