# Can't upgrade 12.04.1 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 and I am trying to upgrade to 12.10. When I launch the update manager there is no notification for the version 12.10. I have already tried changing my settings to alert me of all new versions(not just long-term support releases).