# Ubuntu 12.10 Install

Tags: installation, 12.10, usb-drive

**Hello**

Does anyone know how to install Ubuntu from a flash drive? I think I know how to do it but I don't want to delete my windows...

I have Linux and Windows on the same computer you see that's my problem too i'm not sure how to do it does anybody know?

---

**Edit from response to comments:** I want to replace the Ubuntu 12.04.1 with the 12.10 version.

Comment: Please add more information in your question. Do you want to replace "Linux" with Ubuntu or have all three? The process is very similar to using a Live CD/DVD.

Comment: Well im a beginner at this computer stuff so im not sure but i just want to replace the linux Ubuntu 12.04.1 with the 12.10 version.

Comment: See http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest for instructions on installing from USB, and how to create **Live USB**. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why for how to enable upgrade option from within 12.04.1.

Comment: yeah but the problem  it that i have windows on the same hard drive and i want to keep it...

Comment: You should get an option to upgrade 12.04 to 12.10 when you start the installation. That will not delete Windows. If you don't get that option, tell us how 12.04 was installed previously. Was it WUBI or full install?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have Windows and Ubuntu 12.04.1 installed and running smoothly on your computer, **the best method** might be **starting Ubuntu 12.04.1 normally and upgrading to Ubuntu from within Ubuntu 12.04.1**.

If your system has not already asked if you would like to upgrade, you can run "**Software Sources**", switch to "**Updates**" tab, and make sure that "*Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:*" is followed by "*For any version*".

Then your system will prompt you to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10, or you can as well start "**Software Updater**" manually to make this happen instantly.

Using a live CD/USB for this purpose for such an upgrade might be the **second option**, while a fresh install can also be considered as a **third option** (to replace the current Ubuntu version, for example).