# I cant upgrade the Ubuntu distro version from terminal

Tags: upgrade, apt, dist-upgrade

When I enter `sudo apt-get upgrade` command in terminal, it finds some files to upgrade but not the **Ubuntu new release**. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No facility exists in Update Manager (12.04) to upgrade to 12.10. Why?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

Comment: I don't think that's a dupe as this question is focused on using the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

The `apt-get upgrade` command doesn't update the Ubuntu distro version. The function of this command is update **the installed packages**.

You can get more information with the `man` command using it previous the command that you want to know what do:

```
$ man apt-get

  ....
  upgrade
    Used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the 
    system from the sources enumerated in /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently 
    installed with new versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no 
    circumstances are currently installed packages removed, nor are packages that 
    are not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of currently 
    installed packages that cannot be upgraded without changing the install status 
    of another package will be left at their current version. An update must be 
    performed first so that apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available. 
  ....
```

To upgrade to a new distribution, you run `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

Since 12.04 is a LTS release (Long Term Support), you will first need to go to the window Software Sources and in the last option of the third tab (Updates) state that you are interested in being informed of every new release of Ubuntu (first option in the drop-down list). You will need to enter your code.

Now you can close the window, open the software updater and it will tell you that Ubuntu 12.10 is available.